# Must a self-adjoint operator be surjective when it's injective?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space, $\mathcal{A}  : V \rightarrow V$ be a bounded linear operator satisfying that $(\mathcal{A}u,v) = (u,\mathcal{A}v)$, and $(\mathcal{A}u,u)>0$ if $u \neq 0$. I know that $\mathcal{A}$ is injective because $\mathcal{A}u = 0$ implies $u = 0$.

> Does it hold that $\mathcal{A}$ is surjective? (Maybe use the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is self-adjoint?)

It's easy to see that $\mathcal{A}$ induces another inner product $(u,v)_{\mathcal{A}} = (\mathcal{A}u,v)$. For any bounded linear operator $\mathcal{B}: V \rightarrow V$ with the original inner product, I am not sure the existence and the uniqueness of the adjoint operator:
$$
(B^*u,v)_{\mathcal{A} }= (u, \mathcal{B}v)_{\mathcal{A} }.
$$

I know the answer is yes when $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: There is a class of operators that satisfy this "injective iff surjective" property. They are called Fredholm operators (with Fredholm index $0$). The property you are looking for is called the Fredholm alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the example where $V = l^2$ and $A : V \to V$ is the map
$$ (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \mapsto (x_1, \tfrac 1 2 x_2, \tfrac 1 3 x_3, \dots).$$

$A$ is a bounded linear operator, with norm $1$. $A$ is self-adjoint. And $\langle u, Au \rangle > 0$ for all non-zero $u \in V$.

But $v = (1, \tfrac 1 2, \tfrac 1 3, \dots)$ is an element of $V$ that is not in the image of $A$. Indeed, if $w$ is an element that is mapped by $A$ to $v$, then $w$ would have to be $(1, 1, 1, \dots)$. But $(1, 1, 1, \dots)$ is not actually an element of $l^2$, since it has an infinite $l^2$ norm.

---

**Edit:** Although your hypotheses do not imply that $A$ is surjective, it's worth knowing that they imply a weaker statement, which is that the image of $A$ is *dense* in $V$.

To prove this, consider a $v \in \text{Im}(A)^\perp$. For all $u \in V$, we have $\langle Au, v \rangle = 0$. Taking $u = v$, we see that $\langle Av , v \rangle = 0$. But one of your hypotheses states that the only $v$ that satisfies $\langle Av , v \rangle = 0$ is the zero vector. Thus we've proved that $\text{Im}(A)^\perp = \{ 0 \}$.

[Alternatively, you can prove the same thing using the weaker hypotheses that $A$ is injective and self-adjoint. If $v \in \text{Im}(A)^\perp$, then $\langle Au, v \rangle = 0$ for all $u \in V$. Since $A$ is self-adjoint, this is the same as saying that $\langle u, Av \rangle = 0$ for all $u \in V$. Taking $u = Av$, we obtain $\langle Av, Av \rangle = 0$, i.e. $Av = 0$. Since $A$ is injective, $v$ must be $0$. Thus $\text{Im}(A)^\perp = \{ 0 \}$.]

Anyway, if $W$ is any closed linear subspace of $V$, then $V$ can be written as a direct sum $V = W \oplus W^\perp$. Taking $W$ to be $\overline{\text{Im}(A)}$, we have $W^\perp = \overline{\text{Im}(A)}^\perp = \text{Im}(A)^\perp = \{ 0 \}$. So $V = \overline{\text{Im}(A)} \oplus \{ 0 \} = \overline{\text{Im}(A)}$. Thus $\text{Im}(A)$ is dense in $V$.

At this point you might like to return to our example where $V = l^2$ and where $A$ is the map $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \mapsto (x_1, \tfrac 1 2 x_2, \tfrac 1 3 x_3, \dots)$. Earlier, we showed that $v = (1, \tfrac 1 2, \tfrac 1 3, \dots)$ is not in $\text{Im}(A)$. However, $(1, \tfrac 1 2, \tfrac 1 3, \dots)$ is most certainly contained in the closure, $\overline{\text{Im}(A)}$; indeed, the elements $v_n := (1, \tfrac 1 2, \dots, \tfrac 1 n, 0, 0, \dots)$ are all in $\text{Im}(A)$, and the sequence $\{ v_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $v$ in $l^2$.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on the second question about the existence of the $B^*$? Actually I am wondering whether $B^*$ is bounded linear operator from $V$ to $V$  equiped with $A-$ norm.

Comment: @Chandler Your second question seems like a completely different question to your first! It's also feels like an odd question to ask, because you start with an operator $B$ that is bounded w.r.t. to the _original_ norm, and then you ask whether $B$ has an adjoint w.r.t. the $A$-norm that is bounded w.r.t. the $A$-norm. May I suggest you ask a separate question on math.SE? And if you do so, then could you please take care to word the question as precisely as you can, and explain the motivation for your question in full?

Comment: By the way, if your second question was asking whether, given an operator $B$ bounded w.r.t. to the original norm, there exists an operator $C$ bounded w.r.t. to the original norm such that $\langle Cu, v \rangle_A = \langle u, Bv \rangle_A$ for all $u, v \in V$, then the answer would be "no". First, observe that this question is equivalent to asking whether there exists a $D$, bounded w.r.t. the original norm, such that $DA = AB$. ($D$ would be $C^\star$, the adjoint of $C$ w.r.t. the original norm.)

Comment: Take $V = l^2$, $A: (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \mapsto (x_1, \frac 1 {2!} x_2, \frac 1 {3!}x_3, \dots)$, $B: (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \mapsto (x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots)$. Then $D$ would have to be $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \mapsto (2x_2, 3x_3, 4x_4, \dots)$, but this is not bounded w.r.t. the original norm.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to go to work now, so I won't have time to think about the version of your second question as phrased in your comment. Sorry I can't help.